# Is O(log(n*log n) can be considered as O(log n)

Tags: big-o, asymptotic-complexity

Consider I get f(n)=log(n*log n). Should I say that its O(log(n*log n)?
Or should I do log(n*log n)=log n + log(log n) and then say that the function f(n) is O(log n)?

Comment: What happens when n becomes very large. That's the test...

Comment: no. `log(n)` and `log(n * log(n))` intersect.

Comment: @akonsu - That's kind of irrelevant. O(log(n*log(n))) = O(log(n) + log(log(n))) < O(2*log(n)) = O(log(n)) (since constant factors are irrelevant for big-O).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as you have observed:

```
 log(n*log n) = log(n)  + log(log(n))
```

but think about log(log N) as N->large (as Floris suggests).

For example, let N = 1000, then log N = 3 (i.e. a small number) and log(3) is even smaller,
this holds as N gets huge, i.e. way more than the number of instructions your code could ever generate.

Thus, O(log(n * log n)) = O(log n + k) = O(log(n)) + k = O(log n)

Another way to look at this is that: n * log n << n^2, so in the worse case:

```
  O(log(n^2)) > O(log(n * log n))
```

So, 2*O(log(n)) is an upper bound, and O(log(n * log n)) = O(log n)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). If f(n) = O(log(n*log(n))), then there must exist a positive constant M and real n<sub>0</sub> such that:

> |f(n)| ≤ M |log(n*log(n))|

for all n > n<sub>0</sub>.

Now let's assume (without loss of generality) that n<sub>0</sub> > 0. Then

> log(n) ≥ log(log(n))

for all n > n<sub>0</sub>.

From this, we have:

> log(n(log(n)) = log(n) + log(log(n)) ≤ 2 * log(n)

Substituting, we find that

> |f(n)| ≤ 2*M|log(n))| for all n > n<sub>0</sub>

Since 2*M is also a positive constant, it immediately follows that f(n) = O(log(n)).

Answer (score 0):

Of course in this case simple transformations show both functions differ by a constant factor asymptotically, as shown.

However, I feel like it is worthwhile remind a classic test for analyzing how two functions relate to each other asymptotically. So here's a little more formal proof.

You can check how does `f(x)` relates to `g(x)` by analyzing `lim f(x)/g(x)` when `x->infinity`.

There are 3 cases:

1. **lim** = infinty <=> `O(f(x))` > `O(g(x))`
2. inf > **lim** > 0 <=> `O(f(x))` = `O(g(x))`
3. **lim** = 0 <=> `O(f(x))` < `O(g(x))`

So

```
lim ( log( n * log(n) ) / log n ) =
lim ( log n + log log (n) )  / log n =
lim 1 + log log (n) / log n =
1 + 0 = 1
```

Note: I assumed `log log n / log n` to be trivial but you can do it by [de l'Hospital Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).